# Catch exception in ruby

Tags: ruby, exception

I have a function in ruby

```
def mark_completed
      var_a = self.a
      self.check_something
    end
```

The other function is

```
def check_something(query = nil)
   raise 'Some_exception' if condition_a_satisfy?
      return true
 end
```

See , the function **check_something** is raising exception , What I want is : - "**To catch the exception and return false somehow"**
How can i do it?

Note : - I cannot change my **check_something** function.

Comment: Well then, `rescue` in `mark_completed` in this case.

Comment: Is calling `condition_a_satisfy?` directly an option?

Answer (score 1):

### Rescue RuntimeError in #mark_completed

When you call [Kernel#raise](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) with a string, you're actually raising the [default exception](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Exception.html#class-Exception-label-Defaults), which is [RuntimeError](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/RuntimeError.html). You should catch that explicitly to avoid catching other [exceptions](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Exception.html#class-Exception-label-Built-In+Exception+Classes) that descend from StandardError unintentionally, or courting disaster by rescuing Exception which is almost never a good idea. For example:

```
def mark_completed
  self.check_something
rescue RuntimeError
  false
end
```

This will solve the question you asked in a controlled way, but deliberately side-steps the question of whether raising exceptions is the right thing for the code to do in the first place, or whether other refactorings are possible.

Answer (score -1):

**This does involve changing the method, but this could still be useful to know.**

Hi, I think you’re o looking for a try and catch statement in ruby. This will run Code if there is no error or exception, and if there is it will run specified Code.

For an example:

```
def check_something(query = nil)
begin
# to execute with no exceptions
rescue Exception
# to execute when you hit an exception
ensure
# to execute always
end
```

Comment: You shouldn't rescue `Exception`, though. This is too generic.

Comment: Also, this can't be called try/catch. There's no `try` in ruby. There is `catch`, but it does something else entirely.

Comment: thanks buddy ! I am beginner in ruby and programming , please suggest me from where I can study about catch and try and what is their significance..

Comment: @AnkitKumar Try/Catch (i call it that as I come from a language where rescue ensure is not implemented), is basically a kind of Code block which will find an error, run certain Code if you find an error, and run certain Code if no errors are found. This is useful because you can make your program not stop when it reaches an error, but run certain Code if you do. Here is a website for more about ruby try/catch: https://stackify.com/rescue-exceptions-ruby/